# How can I run shell scripts on a remote linux server using an Angular(8) UI?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, shell, scripting

So, I have been doing MEAN stack web development for some time now. I am normally used to Angular UI development and executing CRUD operations using node servers.

Now, I have a new requirement - Create a UI for running some shell scripts on a remote Linux server.

For example:-

files are located in a path such as **files/bin/example.sh** in the remote server.
I have to be able to perform operations via my UI such as:-

```
example.sh status device name

example.sh start device name
```

How can I do this? Can anyone give me some directions?

Thanks.

Comment: you cannot access files on server from angular directly without using a back end server

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [shelljs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shelljs) npm package to do that. you will have to write a REST API that will execute your shell script from the server-side (Using node js).

ex

```
const shell = require('shelljs')
shell.exec('./path_to_your_file')
```

And then you can call that REST endpoint from your angular application.